# Numeric Categorical Variable in Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I am kind of curious about how sklearn deals with the categorical variables represented by the numbers, such as New York=1 Boston=2 Chicago=3. Will python know that is categorical or just treat it as ordered numeric? I saw a post [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/26yesm/machine_learning_in_r_better_than_in_scikitlearn/) discussing about this issue. I don't know whether it is correct or not.

Also I don't know whether I should change them all into sparse matrix format such as

```
[1,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[0,0,1]
```

What would be the difference between these two format when applied to sklearn library?

If sklearn can't handle categorical variables well, will R beat it for that?

Thanks!

Update:

I saw the duplication question recommended by @larsmans but it actually did not answer my question in terms of the answer [in this post](http://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/26yesm/machine_learning_in_r_better_than_in_scikitlearn/), which said that sklearn can't deal well with categorical variables and how does it compare with the package in R. I also saw some posts before that it is OK with large dataset but will affect small dataset. From @larsmans, it seemed that except for tree algorithm, other methods should transfer the numerical categorical variables to dummies. Actually I have more than 3000 categories for each variable. I don't think it is efficient to change them all to the sparse matrix using DictVectorizer or oneHotEncoder will be an efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is what you need [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html)

To represent a multi-class categorical variables in plain numbers may not be a good idea. The best practice should be transforming the n-class categorical variable into n boolean variables. In your example, 3 new boolean variables should be created to mark "==New York", "==Boston", and "==Chicago".

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
v = DictVectorizer(sparse = True)


D = [{"Value" : 100, "City": "New York"},
     {"Value" : 70, "City": "Boston"},
     {"Value" : 99, "City": "Chicago"},
     ]

X = v.fit_transform(D)
print v.get_feature_names()
print X
```

Output:

```
['City=Boston', 'City=Chicago', 'City=New York', 'Value']
[[   0.    0.    1.  100.]
 [   1.    0.    0.   70.]
 [   0.    1.    0.   99.]]
```

Comment: actually my variable has more than 3000 categories I don't know whether it is going to be efficient to do so

Comment: @MYjx, you may choose to use a sparse matrix to store the features. The high cardinality shouldn't be a problem as long as your sample size is not overwhelming.

Comment: thx! actually I only have 4000 records. I am afraid if I have too many variables the df will be too small

Comment: Sparse matrix storage is in fact the default.